# Get a string out of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, phpmyadmin

Good day! I've created a file send.php to send an info about orders to my gmail. Almost everything is ok, but I can't send names of products from cart. I have to send just a string(title) from the DB on mail. How can I get a title from $g which is a row?

```
<?php

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';


$g = $_SESSION['cart_list'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$c = $single["title"];


$title = "";
$body = "
<h2></h2>
<b></b> $name<br>
<b></b> $tel<br><br>
<b></b>$c<br>
";

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
try {
$mail->isSMTP();   
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {$GLOBALS['status'][] = $str;};


$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Username   = '';
$mail->Password   = '';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->setFrom(''); 


$mail->addAddress('');  


$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $title;
$mail->Body = $body;


if ($mail->send()) {$result = "success";} 
else {$result = "error";}
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
$result = "error";
$status = "{$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

echo json_encode(["result" => $result, "resultfile" => $rfile, "status" => $status]);
```

order.php(With products, sum, inlines, submit)

```
<?php
require_once "db.php";
require_once "header.php";
?> <br>
<div class="text-center">
</div><br>
<main>
<div class="container">
<section class='text-center mb-4'>
<div class='row'>
<?php $s = 0; ?>
<?php foreach( $_SESSION['cart_list'] as $single ) : ?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-offset-1 
mb-5">
<div class='card'>
<div class='view overlay'>
<div class='qwe'>
<img class='card-img-top' src='/img/products/<?php echo $single['img'];? 
>.jpg'>
</div>
 <div class='mask rgba-white-slight'></div>

</div>
<div class='card-body text-center'>
  <div class="grey-text">     
<div class='title'><h5><?php echo $single['title'];?></h5></div>
</div>
<br>
<h5>
  <strong><?php echo $single['brand'];?>
    <span class='badge red mr-1'>
    <?php echo $single['category'];?>
    </span>
  </strong>
</h5>
<h4 class='font-weight-bold blue-text'>
  <strong><?php echo $single['price'];?>$</strong>
</h4>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php $s += $single['price']; ?>
<?php $g = $_SESSION['cart_list']  ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</section>


<hr><section class='text-center mb-4 font-weight-bold display-4'>
<label class="count" id="summ"><?php echo $s; ?>$</label>

</section>
    <p>
    <a href="cart.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> 
</button></a> <br> <br>
    </p>
<form action="send.php" method="post">
<div class="text-center">
<input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше " aria-label="" required>
<input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="" aria-label="" required>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="" required>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</main>
</div>
<?php require_once "footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: I don't see `$d` anywhere in your code, I only see `$g`. Besides, only you know under which key that information is stored.

Comment: My bad, it's $g. DB is named "details", I have columns: id, title, description, img, price, category, brand. They are in this order

Comment: Can you share the full structure of `$g`? You can do `var_export`, `var_dump` or `print_r` to dump the contents of the variable.

Comment: I've added php page with session paramets. Maybe I should connect db.php to send.php?

Comment: What you've added isn't relevant to the issue. Can you please add a dump of the cart so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: sorry, it's already solluted on another forum. $name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$g = $_SESSION['cart_list'];
$c = serialize(array_map(function($e){return $e['title'];}, $g));

Comment: Thanks for help!

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complicated, but it reveals what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the names is as simple as the following:

```php
$titles = implode(', ', array_column($g, 'title'));
```

Assuming a dummy cart like this (I included a cyrillic value since you mentioned that in your follow up question):

```
$g = [
    ['title' => 'This is a title', 'something' => 'else'],
    ['title' => 'Some things', 'something' => 'else'],
    ['title' => 'Word', 'something' => 'else'],
    ['title' => 'Владимир', 'something' => 'else'],
];
```

the result will be a string:

```
This is a title, Some things, Word, Владимир
```

*How it works*

First we extract just the titles; `array_column($g, 'title')` will produce an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => 'This is a title',
    1 => 'Some things',
    2 => 'Word',
    3 => 'Владимир',
)
```

After that, all that is left is to `implode` all those array elements into a single string. I used a comma as the glue delimiter, but you could use whatever you need.